# NoSuchMethodError exception on okhttp3/Request@Builder

Tags: android, android-espresso, okhttp

I'm getting below error when I ran espresso test getting below,

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method get()Lokhttp3/Request$Builder; in class Lokhttp3/Request$Builder; or its super classes (declaration of 'okhttp3.Request$Builder' appears in /data/app/appXXX.debug-2/base.apk:classes3.dex)
```

I'm trying to connect to rest endpoint through espresso to get the configuration.

My build.gradle configuration is as below,

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was proguard was removing okhttp3 unused classes. Updated the proguard config to keep okhttp3 files and it's working like charm!